# ssrs parameter showing up in report manager but not through url

Tags: url, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a report that works like a charm in visual studio, and the Report Manager interface. I have one hidden parameter (Origin person id) and two visible parameters (date and person id).
[image: report manager ui has both parameters show]

the options for person ID should only be filled after the Origin person ID has been set, (which is what happens in visual studio and the Report manager if i set origin person id to visible and set it by hand).

However the issue comes when I try to use a url to view the report, I only get

[image: Only the date parameter shows up when in the url view]

I do not believe it is something to do with the url not passing a value to the hidden parameter because if i set person ID to hidden and add a default value, then the report works fine. I have also checked the log files for the report server, as well as looking at the traffic on the browser and no errors are being thrown on either end.

lastly if I just fill in the date and click view report in the url view, I get the error "The 'PersonID' parameter is missing a value".

anyone have any insight as of to why this may be happening?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is the parameter was set to hidden the first time you deployed the report to the Report Server.  Youll need to check the settings for the parameter on the server.

You should see some breadcrumb navigation at the top of the url
[image]

Click on the report name and it should take you to the settings.

Follow the links to view the parameter settings and check if the PersonID param is set to hidden?

[image]